# Removing whitespace formatting from CFBuilder / Eclipse code editor

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I must have accidentally hit a shortcut, and am now getting formatting info  in my code, and can't work out how to get rid of it...

Here is a screen dump..  http://www.assetmedia.com.au/editorStuff.gif

Anyone know how I can turn this off?

Many Thanks in advance!

Jason

**UPDATE**

Found it.. thank you Mike Henke for a blog post which I found..

The characters can be toggled with  "ctrl + ."  ..

Thanks Mike!  http://henke.ws/post.cfm/toggle-whitespace-in-eclipse-cfeclipse-and-cfbuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update, as per [Ray Camden](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/4/30/Eclipse-Tip--Whitespace-characters-visible-when-they-are-turned-off):

> the key combo I had hit - ctrl+.

Choose Preferences from the Window menu and type whitespace in the search box. This should take you to the Text Editors panel where you can deselect 'Show whitespace characters'

[image]

Comment: Thanks Antony.. 'Show whitespace characters' isn't selected.. if I do select it and apply I get more characters overlaying the ones I already have, but I am still getting these characters even when 'Show whitespace characters' is not selected..

Comment: Just re-read your Update there Ray.. found it as well.. correct ctrl+. does the trick.. thank you!

Comment: An update on this one.. I found that on mac it is Cmd+. (command + period) removes the formatting.